# Setting a label.Text from a comboBox.DisplayMember in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Forgive me if this is a rather simple question but I can't figure it out.

I have a frontend build in WPF.
It has a combobox with a datasource from a localDB.
The comboBox has a DisplayMember that gets filled at runtime.

I also have a text label and I want its text property to be whatever the displaymember is at runtime. The displaymember value is an object the user selects via the comboBox dropdown list, for example shoes.

```
comboBox.DataSource = ProductLogic.GetProduct();
comboBox.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
```

If I call it like this:

```
label.Text = comboBox.DisplayMember
```

It gets the value at code-time (which is "ProductName", but I need i the text value to be whatever it is at runtime. For example "Shoes". How would I go about this?

Comment: Have you considered simply binding the `Text` of the label to the `DisplayMember` property of your combobox? (in WPF / the XAML)

Comment: A WPF `ComboBox` has no `DisplayMember` nor `DisplayMember` property.

Comment: It does -> ListControl.DisplayMember

Comment: The `ListControl` is a control from Windows Forms (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=netframework-4.8). Are you sure this is WPF? From your last comment it sounds more like this is a Windows Forms based application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayMember` holds the **name of the property** which value is displayed in combobox (or any other control which supports it). So the value of `DisplayMember` is not changing. You probably want to use `Text` property.

`label.Text = comboBox.Text`